# Rowspan for rows (not for headers) in DOJO grid...

Tags: dojox.grid.datagrid, html-table

I have a scenario where i need to group the cells alone (not for the headers).

eg...
A A1 1
A A2 2
A A3 3
A A4 4
B B1 1
B B2 2
B B3 3
B B4 4

In the above table, instead of having 4 A's and 3 B's in the first column, can we merge them in to a single cell ? Something like...

       A1 1
A  A2 2
       A3 3
       A4 4

       B1 1
B  B2 2
       B3 3

But the thing is  the number of records per group may vary... ( 10 records for A and 5 records for B like)

Thanks in advance..

I found examples with markup but the headers and rows are static and follow same pattern.

Regards,
Sankaranarayanan Ekambaranathan.

Answer (score 2):

This requirement seems tough. However what about trying a tree-grid? You may find a sample at http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/grid/tests/test_treegrid.html

```
-A
    A1   1
    A2   2
    A3   3
    A4   4
-B
    B1   1
    B2   2
    B3   3
    B4   4
+C
```